# How to correctly verify existence of a record in database when designing an ETL based on Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am in the process of creating an ETL and fraud management module using flink to analyze a sequence of real time credit card transactions.

All transactions are received by an exposed API that pushes the data into a Kafka topic.
First, the received data needs to be checked and cleaned, and then stored in a database.
The next step is a fraud analysis of these transactions.

In this first step, with Flink, I have to check in the Card database that the card is known before continuing. The problem is, there are around a billion cards in this database and new card could be added over time.
So I'm not sure if I could cache the entire card number in memory or how to effectively handle this check: Is Flink able to handle some kind of sliding cache to check the card for existence in batch?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Is Flink able to handle some kind of sliding cache to check the card for existence in batch?"

Comment: I was thinking of a sort of cache storing the nth most recent seen values in a stream.

Comment: You could state TTL to expire values that haven't been needed for a while.

Answer (score 0):

What you might do is to mirror the card database into Flink's key-partitioned state, either on-heap, or using RocksDB if you want to this to spill to disk. Key-partitioned state is sharded across the cluster, so if you do want to keep the entire card database in memory, you can scale up the cluster until that's feasible.

To keep only recently seen values, you could rely on [state TTL](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl) to expire records that haven't been accessed recently.

An alternative: Flink SQL has support for doing streaming lookup joins against JDBC databases, and you can configure caching for that.